# Why $p(t)=e^{2\pi it}$ is open?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I try to show that  $p: \Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb S^1\subset \mathbb{R}^2$,$p(t)=e^{2\pi it}$ is identifaction map.

> - I proved $p$ is the continuous and surjective map.

$\textbf{Question:}$: I can't see how to prove $p$ is an open map?

Comment: There are two topology on $\mathbb{S}^1$ which are the quotient topology ($p^{-1}(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$) and induced topology by $\mathbb{R}^2$ ($U=V\cap \mathbb{S}^1$). Probably two topology are the same. I dont know whether or not the definition of $p$ is important.

Comment: Show every open interval maps to a set open within the circle.